# Parallel Approvers

Tags: approval-process

In Salesforce Approval process, can we have parallel approvers ? . And the approval will proceed to the next step only after getting approval from all of them ?

For example, A and B are approvers.

An approval request is sent to both A & B at the same time.

In order for the record to be approved both A & B must "Approve" the action.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Create an Approval Step](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm&language=en). In step 10 it says:

> **Require unanimous approval from all selected approvers.** The record is
>   only approved if all of the approvers approve the request. The
>   approval request is rejected if any of the approvers reject the
>   request.

So you need to specify **multiple approvers in the Automatically assign to approver(s) option** and then choose **Require unanimous approval from all selected approvers**.